# Dynamic Ordering and Customization in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have a large dataset with observation values over time. I am using `plotly` to visualize the trend.

Currently, because I have specific custom colors, widths, and line types, I have been treating each subject as a separate trace and manually rearranging them every time a new value comes in -- wanting the legend order to match the most recent values.

I'm close to a more elegant solution, but am unsure how to apply the `width` argument and also how to order the legend so the Subject with the highest most recent value is first (ie Susan has lowest 2000 value so would be last).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# raw data
df <-
  tribble(
    ~Year, ~Subject, ~Value,
    1980, 'A', 100,
    1990, 'A', 200, 
    2000, 'A', 250,
    1980, 'B', 400,
    1990, 'B', 300,
    2000, 'B', 100,
    1980, 'C', 200,
    1990, 'C', 100,
    2000, 'C', 500
  )

# each subject has specific custom viz elements
custom_stuff <-
  tribble(
    ~Subject, ~Name, ~LineColor, ~LineType, ~LineWidth,
    'A', 'John', 'blue', 'solid', 2,
    'B', 'Susan', '#ef0107', 'dash', 1,
    'C', 'Subject C', 'orange', 'dot', 1
  )

# i'm currently transposing the data like this
df_wide <-
  df |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'Subject', values_from = 'Value')

# and then manually applying my custom elements and manually ordering the traces based on most recent value. yuck.
plot_ly(df_wide, x = ~Year) |> 
  add_trace(y = ~C, name = 'Subject C', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
            line = list(shape = 'spline', color = 'orange', width = 1, dash = 'dot')) |> 
  add_trace(y = ~A, name = 'John', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
            line = list(shape = 'spline', color = 'blue', width = 2, dash = 'solid')) |> 
  add_trace(y = ~B, name = 'Susan', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
            line = list(shape = 'spline', color = '#ef0107', width = 1, dash = 'dash'))

# i'd like to do something more dynamic and elegant like this, but unsure how to handle width and ordering of legend.
custom_df <-
  df |> 
  inner_join(custom_stuff, by = 'Subject')

plot_ly(custom_df, 
        x = ~Year,
        y = ~Value,
        color = ~I(LineColor),
        name = ~Name,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines',
        linetype = ~I(LineType),
        # width = ~I(LineWidth),
        line = list(shape = 'spline', smoothing = 1.3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach which builds on your first approach using a wide dataset but adds the traces dynamically using `Reduce` and determines the order in which subjects/traces using some data wrangling:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# Order of subjects and traces
subject_order <- df |>
  slice_max(Year, by = Subject) |>
  arrange(desc(Year), desc(Value)) |>
  mutate(Subject = fct_inorder(Subject)) |>
  pull(Subject) |>
  levels()

plot_ly(df_wide, x = ~Year) |>
  Reduce(\(x, y) {
    custom_stuff <- custom_stuff |> filter(Subject == y)
    add_trace(
      x,
      y = reformulate(y), name = custom_stuff$Name, type = "scatter", mode = "lines",
      line = list(
        shape = "spline", color = custom_stuff$LineColor,
        width = custom_stuff$LineWidth,
        dash = custom_stuff$LineType
      )
    )
  }, x = subject_order, init = _)
```

[image]

Comment: I really like this approach! Thanks for the help! I need to learn more about `Reduce`.